# How do I show the parent term on a custom taxonomy template (not the ID)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
echo $term->name; 
echo $term->description; 
echo $term->parent;
```

Name gives the name.
Description gives the description.
Parent gives the parent ID, not the term.

How do I get the parent term (the word)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again use the [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function:

```
$curr_taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), $curr_taxonomy );

if ( $term !== FALSE && $term->parent > 0 )
    $parent_term = get_term_by('id', (int) $term->parent, $curr_taxonomy );
else
    $parent_term = false;
```